# parsing json with perl

Tags: perl, json

I have a url which should be invoked from my perl script with a specific parameter. On invoking the url it returns me a JSON. I will have to parse this JSON in the same script. What is the best way to get this done in perl. A pseudo code would be of help :)

Comment: Start with a trip to http://json.org and http://cpan.org (the former will redirect to the latter ;-) Now go "get the c0dez".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
use LWP::Simple qw(get);
use JSON        qw(from_json);

my $url     = "http://example.com/get/json";
my $decoded = from_json(get($url));
```

See docs for [LWP::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP%3a%3aSimple) and [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON) for more details.